# Are LAPD reliability and flow-control messages (e.g. RR and RNR) considered to be data-plane or control-plane messages?

Tags: sdn, terminology

Ethernet, IPv4, IPv6, MPLS are all examples of datagram networks where each frame or packet is forwarded in a mostly stateless manner, independent of earlier and later packets.

In such networks the hop-by-hop forwarding is not guaranteed to be reliable; reliability is implemented in the transport layer, e.g. by TCP.

In this type of network the distinction between the data plane and the control plane is very clear and well understood:

- The data plane is responsible for actually forwarding each received data packet, which includes consulting the forwarding table to decide where the packet should go next.
- The control plane is responsible for populating the correct routes into the forwarding tables by running control-plane protocols that discover the topology of the network and calculate the best path to each destination. Note that the control plane could be distributed (e.g. OSPF) or centralized (e.g. OpenFlow) or some combination.

But what about stateful reliable datalink / network layers where reliability and flow-control are implemented on a hop-by-hop basis?

A historical example of this is LAPD in X.25 networks (Q.921, see https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Topics/125.htm).

In LAPD we have messages that contain the actual data (I and UI frames), which are clearly data plane messages.

But LAPD also has other types of messages that are used to implement reliability and flow-control (RR, RNR, REJ frames for example). These message do not actually contain any end-user data payload. My question is: **are these messages considered to be control-plane messages or data-plane messages or is it a gray area?**

Or to ask the same question more broadly: are all datalink messages considered to be data-plane messages, even if some of the messages are related to reliability and flow-control rather than actually carrying user-data payloads?

I am asking because I have a network where we use such a stateful datalink protocol (not LAPD, but similar in many ways) and I want know whether the statement "we have a SDN controller that implements a centralized control plane" makes sense in such an environment or not.

Comment: IMO, the the distinction between control and data plane would be the intent of the message, not the transport mechanism.  FDDI and Token Ring have similar control mechanisms, often in the same frame as the data.

Comment: @KevinMason So, would you call LAPD RR and RNR message (or the equivalent) control-plane or data-plane messages?

Comment: Control plane since session control is the purpose.

Comment: @kevin Yes, that was my original intuition as well. But that line of reasoning implies that one can never have a fully centralized control plane in the presence of such a datalink protocol.

Comment: LAPD/X25 does not create an end to end view of the path, it is purely hop by hop decision each time. So the scope of the control plane is just that link and the next hop switching decision by the receiving node. Any centralized control plan would have to aggregate all the individual links.

Part of the problem is the concept of a discrete control plane was not really developed

Comment: @kevin Indeed LAPD (layer 2) is purely hop-by-hop and does not have any concept of an end-to-end path. X.25 (layer 3) does have the concept of an end-to-end path, namely a virtual circuit (VC or PVC). Although the picture is a bit blurred because X.25 is a service protocol (it defines only the DCE-DTE protocol) and does not standardize the signaling inside the network (it does not define the PSE-PSE protocol).

Comment: Agreed on both points, it is very blurry and depends on how you look at it